# Regular Expression, select bullet point between word letter

Tags: regex

**I Have** "`...h.e.l.l.o...w.o.r.l.d...`"

**I would like**  "`hello world`" **or** "`..hello...world..`"

**I Have tried:**
 `/(?:\w)(\.)(?:\w)/`

`/\w(\.)\w/`

`/[^\w]\.[^\w]/`

**Any Help?**

Comment: Use a string replace function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use this regex in search:

```
(?<=\w)\.(?=\w)
```

And use `""` for replacement.

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/hC4iP0/2)

Comment: Ah awesome, I was using http://www.regexr.com/ & not getting on too well with it. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this:

```
\b[.]\b
```

With "" in replacement